# Inconsistent terminal settings across directories

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal

This is a bit hard to explain, but for some reason, when I cd to one specific directory in my file tree, the terminal and the displays within the terminal appear different only inside this directory.

For example, right now I have the default colors set so that the background is black, the text color of the directories are blue, and the text color for files should show up as white. But when I cd into this particular directory and type "ls" the files are listed in blue. The typed command at the cursor is also in blue, when in other directories it is in white. I should also mention that when I run python, say, the application interface comes up as blue as well. But typing "ls -a" the output shows up as white, "ls -l" and the output shows up as blue, and "ls -la" has the output in white again.

Also the name the directory that I am in usually shows up before the "$" sign followed by the cursor. However, in this case the cursor appears enmeshed in the middle of the directory name and a symbol like this appears:

```
[[00m
```

at the beginning of the line in the middle of the directory name.

One more thing. When I resize the terminal to be full screen, everything goes back to the way it should be - the cursor is at the end of the directory name, "ls" shows the files in white, etc...

I work in and out of this directory a lot so it is kind of annoying and I want to be able to go back to the settings I had before. Any suggestions?

Here is information about the terminal:

MATE Terminal 1.2.1

The OS is Linux Mint 13 3.2.0-23-generic (#36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012)

Finally, I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, but the OS is actually on a separate hard drive than the directory is on.

Comment: What happens if you type `PS1="#"` then try it again?

Comment: Nothing changes.

Comment: When you say nothing changes, do you mean “the behaviour is unchanged: it still changes behaviour in different directories”, or “it no longer changes behaviour in different directories”?

Comment: The former: it has no effect, the behavior is unchanged: it still changes behavior in different directories

Comment: I don't know, but I would suggest some experimenting. First make sure you backup. Then `cd just-outside-strange-dir` `mkdir tmp` `cp -a -t tmp strange-dir` test tmp/strange-dir `cp -a strange-dir tmp/new-name` test tmp/new-name, `rm tmp/strange-dir/*` test etc.

Comment: I've tried all those commands. When I cd into the copied directory ("tmp"), the terminal behaves exactly as it should: the text color of files is white, the cursor is where it is supposed to be, etc...